# How to increase tab spacing on top in Atom?

Tags: tabs, atom-editor

The picture attached shows the problem. 
[image: Picture showing the problem]

As you can see from the picture, the tabs are clustered together.

How can I space them out so that they spread out evenly in the entire space?

Comment: It looks like this _feature_ was introduced lately. My v1.8.0 Atom behaves the  same way as your do. I didn't have such a problem back in v1.7.4.

Comment: https://discuss.atom.io/t/the-tabs-got-shorter-in-v1-8-0-what-happened-how-do-i-go-back/29791

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a better solution: Go to Settings > Themes > theme settings (the gear icon next to the UI theme dropbox) and use the **Tab Sizing** option

source: https://discuss.atom.io/t/the-tabs-got-shorter-in-v1-8-0-what-happened-how-do-i-go-back/29791

Comment: Don't hesitate to accept this answer if it solved your problem (tick on the left) :)

Answer (score 5):

You have to edit the custom stylesheet. In the menu bar go to "Atom" > "Stylesheet..." and copy this into the custom stylesheet file:

```
.tab-bar .tab {
  flex-grow: 1 !important;
  max-width: none;
}
```

After saving the tabs should spread.

Comment: It works now! I wonder why Atom started to behave this way though. It must be related to the recent updates.